# Systems of linear differential equations - eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system of equations

$
\begin{cases} 
x_1^{'}(t)=x_1(t)+3x_2(t) \\ 
x_2^{'}(t)=3x_1(t)-2x_2(t)-x_3(t) \\ 
x_3^{'}=-x_2(t)+x_3(t)\end{cases}
$.

First, I create the column vectors $X$ and $X^{'}$. Then the matrix $$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0  \\
3 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, I find the eigenvalues, $-4,3,1$ and their corresponding eigenvectors $(-3,5,1)^T (-3,-2,1)^T (1,0,3)^T$.

I'm just not sure how to take it from here and solve the system of differential equations. I want a diagonal matrix $D$ so that I can read the solutions easy, but I'm not sure how to do it.

**EDIT**

Building on @Francisco 's answer, I'd have that:

$$X=c_1  (-3,5,1)^T  e^{-4t}   + c_2 (-3,-2,1)^T e^{3t} + c_3 (1,0,3)^T e^{t} $$.  But I believe this could be written in a simpler form.

Comment: Have you tried writing the matrix in a basis of its eigenvectors? (i.e in the form $S M S^{-1}$) where M is a diagonal matrix

Comment: To write $X^{'}=S^{-1}DSX$?

Comment: You have $X'(t)=A X(t)$. Then $X=\vec v e^{\lambda t}$ (where $\vec v$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue) is a solution to the system. The general solution is given by $X=c_1 \vec v_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} +c_2 \vec v_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} + c_3 \vec v_3 e^{\lambda_3 t}$ where $c_1$ $c_2$ and $c_3$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: What would be a faster approach?

Comment: @Francisco I updated my question. Also, is there a wiki page for the formula you mentioned?

Comment: Those can't be the eigenvalues for this matrix.  The trace of the matrix equals the sum of the eigenvalues.  The sum of your eigenvalues is -2, but the trace is 0.

Comment: I did calculate +1 bur wrote -1. Edited now.

Comment: Now, I found the solution $$\begin{cases}      
x_1= -3c_1   e^{-4t}  - 3c_2e^{3t}    +c_3e^{t}  \\
x_2=  5c_1 e^{-4t}      -2c_2e^{3t}   \\
x_3=            c_1 e^{-4t}              +         c_2e^{3t} +3c_3e^{t}. 
\end{cases}  $$ is this correct, yes or no?

Comment: @jacob: Were you supposed to solve the system just bu eigenvalues or you could use another approach? I see anothe approach which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ that you have is symmetric. So it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. The eigenvectors you have found are mutually orthogonal (which they must be because they correspond to different eigenvalues.) So, if you normalize your eigenvectors and make those normalized vectors the columms of a matrix $U$, then $U^{T}U=I$ is automatic, and $U^{T}AU=D$ is diagonal. Explicitly,
$$
        U = \left[
            \begin{matrix}
                -\frac{3}{\sqrt{35}} & -\frac{3}{\sqrt{14}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \\ 
                 \frac{5}{\sqrt{35}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{14}} & 0 \\
                 \frac{1}{\sqrt{35}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}  & \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}
            \end{matrix}\right]
$$
The inverse of $U$ is the transpose $U^{T}$ of $U$. And,
$$
                U^{T}AU = \left[\begin{matrix}-4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]=D.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
                A = U\left[\begin{matrix}-4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]U^{T}=U DU^{T}.
$$
The general solution is expressed in terms of $a=x_{1}(0)$, $b=x_{2}(0)$, $c=x_{3}(0)$ as
$$
      \left[\begin{matrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\end{matrix}\right] =
      e^{tA}\left[\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right] = 
      Ue^{tD}U^{T}\left[\begin{matrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{matrix}\right] =
      U\left[\begin{matrix}
              e^{-4t} & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & e^{3t} & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & e^{t}\end{matrix}\right]U^{T}
       \left[\begin{matrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Comment: This would be the same as 
$$\begin{cases}      
x_1= -3c_1   e^{-4t}  - 3c_2e^{3t}    +c_3e^{t}  \\
x_2=  5c_1 e^{-4t}      -2c_2e^{3t}   \\
x_3=            c_1 e^{-4t}              +         c_2e^{3t} +3c_3e^{t}. 
\end{cases}$$   yes?

Comment: The forms are equivalent, except that the constants in mine are $x_{1}(0)$, $x_{2}(0)$, $x_{3}(0)$, while your constants are not that. Yours are $x_{1}(0)=-3c_{1}-3c_{2}+c_{3}$, etc. Mine will be the same if you set $a=-3c_{1}-3c_{2}+c_{3}$, $b=\dots$, etc.

Comment: @jacob Look at this [pdf](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/differential-equations-and-exp-at/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.10sum.pdf), is from an MIT course. It cleared things up a little bit for me, I wasn't familiar with this way of expressing a solution of a system of ODEs.